# Looking at the database on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am attempting to take a look at the data on my heroku instance. 
I'd like to be able to view the database on their server..

I don't want to pull it down to my local system.. More to the point I don't want wait that long, to take a look at the data.

Lets assume I push my current database of 8 million books(and all the meta data associated) up to heroku. Then in two months I add another 12 million. (I'm still in development mode)
If I have a problem with one batch of data, I don't think it's feasible to pull down the whole database.

*I suppose I could do crunches while I wait on the download of the gigs of data. I hear that's what old programmers did during compiles.*

---

I've looked at [Viewing database in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052419/viewing-database-in-heroku) and it's just a "Can't do it."
Is that true?  We can't look at the live data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(untested but seem it is what you are looking for.. )

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console

Comment: The plugin has been deprecated now. :(

Comment: From the readme "This service has been deprecated. Please use heroku pg:psql instead." Which is definitely the best answer and is listed below as a separate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14793836/2098573

Answer (score 18):

You can use [JackDB (http://www.jackdb.com)](https://www.jackdb.com/).

JackDB is a database client in your web browser that has OAuth integration with Heroku. It lets you list your Heroku apps and their respective datasources and then connect to them to run SQL queries. See the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20140902104513/http://www.jackdb.com:80/docs/data-sources/heroku.html) for details of how to use it with Heroku.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

---

There's also the [JackDB Heroku plugin](https://github.com/jackdb/jackdb-heroku-plugin) for the Heroku CLI. The plugin let's you run `heroku jackdb` from your command line to connect to your default database. There are additional options if you have more than one database and want to explicitly select which one you'd like to connect to.

To install it:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/jackdb/jackdb-heroku-plugin.git
```

To connect to your default database:

```
$ heroku jackdb
```

---

*Full disclosure:* I'm the founder of [JackDB](https://www.jackdb.com/).

Comment: JackDB no longer free, any other solutions?

Answer (score 14):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Heroku Postgres can be attached to a Heroku application via the CLI:
`$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev`

To establish a psql session with your remote database use `heroku pg:psql`.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
heroku pg:psql
```

You'll get to know next steps automatically

Answer (score 3):

To view a database directly from Heroku, I just create a 'Dataclip' of the entire database, at https://dataclips.heroku.com/ . You can alternatively get there from the postgreSQL app. From this page, do a SQL query to view the desired data.

If you are unsure which tables are in the database, view them with:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "view the database". If you're looking for a bona fide SQL console, you're probably out of luck; however, there's always `heroku console` which gets you access to an IRB session attached to your app and its Heroku database. From there, you can use the usual commands like `Book.where("title = ?", @title)` or `Book.count` or whatever you need.

Comment: Ah well.. I was thinking of a console.  The problem I have with the book.where is I want books.where, and I'd want to see them in a list.  Not an object where I'd then have to write code to get them to display. It seems quite clunky to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't a perfect answer, but the best way to get in is with the console IMO.

To make that a little easier I've put a class method on some of my models to print them. One example from my app is:

```
class User

  def self.list
    puts "ID. Name  -  Email\n"
    self.all.each do |user|
      puts "#{user.id}.  #{user.name}  -  #{user.email}\n"
    end
  end

end
```

In console you can just call `User.list` to get the list.

Now this method is not very well optimized, and it would be better if it was written so it could be chained to the end of a query, but you get the basic idea.

It's a little bit cludgy but making a display helper method like this is probably the quickest way to introspect your data on Heroku.

Otherwise my advice would be contact them and ask for recommendations, in my experience the Heroku staff are very responsive and helpful with such requests.

I hope this gives you an idea or two.

Comment: Not really all that flexible, but thanks.. I am struggling with my heroku migration, and though being able to see the data isn't my biggest hurtle, it is one.  AGAIN Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect directly to Shared Heroku instances - if you use a dedicated Postgres Heroku addon then you are able to connect directly with PG tools from your local system. However, there is a significant cost jump to do this.

Comment: Not with the new shared postgres add-on, which is still beta.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but thought I'd answer in case anyone was interested.  I have been using [PG Commander](https://eggerapps.at/pgcommander/) to view my databases both locally and on heroku. It's not free (£28 at the moment) but it is very good.

Go to your [Heroku databases](https://postgres.heroku.com/databases/) and all of the login details will be there.

Comment: this is a nuts old question.. pgadmin is a free app and it's really easy to hook up to heroku.. so you can see the database that is live on heroku.